# MySQL as a database server

Tags: c#, mysql

Is there any way to configure mySql as a database server with concurrency access?

I want to develop a windows application with a open source database where multiple access at the same time. as per the research I did on the internet, Mysql is the best but just want to make sure that Mysql capabilities in the above scenario.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Ofcourse it is capable of that, which modern RDBMS isn't? It might not be the best but it is capable of what you are asking

Comment: Even Facebook still use MySQL.

Comment: @invisal yeah I know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you're misunderstanding something, but I'm not sure what, so I'll just explain stuff a bit :-)

MySQL's single and sole purpose is what you describe. It's to store data and allow it to be accessed concurrently without too many problems.

Your question is a bit like asking "Is there any way to use a hammer to hit a nail? I have a large amount of nails here, and I need to fix some pieces of wood to each other, and I need something to slam them in. Will a hammer do?"

That said, besides MySQL, there's also nice alternatives like PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL is a bit more full-featured, and has recently been taking over MySQL in popularity. Also, "MariaDB" is, effectively, the new name of the latest MySQL version, so you might want to google for that.

Finally, since you want to develop a Windows application, maybe neither of these databases are a good choice - if every user needs to install a database server in order to use your application, installation will be difficult and error-prone (believe me - I have once, maintained the installers for a Windows application that depends on a MySQL server on the user's computer, and it's *hell*). You could also look into SQLite, a database (which also supports concurrent access) that you can bundle immediately with the program you're making. It's really just a library that you link into your program, so it's not a server at all. But it's a full-featured SQL database.

Comment: my requirement is to have a database in a central location which is 24X7 up and the users can login any time. I know that the servers like SQL and Oracle are the best for this but my client wants to have a opensource alternative. I have worked with SQLite but can did not try it for this scenario. Would you mind give me a sample connection string and configuration tips?

Comment: I have MySQL running 24 hours per day, 30 days per month, 365 days per years. I can login any time and MySQL support multiple connection by default (if you want more connection, you can increase it manually, but I believe the default setting is enough for you). **The most important thing is to enable remote access.** if you want it to be accessed from remote computer.